# Yii2 update a record based on form in a view file

Tags: yii2

I tried to update one field of record based on value in a form. The form are placed within a modal in a view file.

**view**

```
Modal::begin([
'header' => '<h3>Update Payment Reference</h3>',
'toggleButton' => ['label' => 'Pay','class' => 'btn btn-success'],
]); ?>

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'pcpayreference')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= Html::submitButton('Update', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
<?php Modal::end();
```

But I have no idea how to pass those value to my controller so it can update whatever the user have input and submitted.

**Controller**

```
public function actionPay($id)
{
    $model = Purchase::findOne($id);

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {

        $model->pcstatus = 'Paid';
        $model->pcpaydate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $model->save();

    return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->pcid]);
    }
}
```

I'm new to Yii framework. Any help is much appreciated.

**EDIT**

The only thing I want to do is to update only this field (current record/view) into database instead of update the whole field.

[image]

Comment: it means when your form will submitted, you will got all data into post / Yii::$app->request->post() , you can dump it, otherwise this will work which is defined.

Comment: i think something is missing in my active form, i got Bad Request (#400)
Missing required parameters: id when submit the form.

Comment: please check my answer and try second solution in bottom, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must set action in your form with id, it will work

```
    Modal::begin([
    'header' => '<h3>Update Payment Reference</h3>',
    'toggleButton' => ['label' => 'Pay','class' => 'btn btn-success'],
    ]); ?>

        <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
                     'action' => ['controller/pay','id'=>$id],
    ]); ?>

 <?= $form->field($model, 'pcpayreference')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= Html::submitButton('Update', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
<?php Modal::end();
```

Comment: i did try it.but weirdly i got blank screen after submit.

Comment: try debugging.. what you are getting in post array

Comment: It is working now. I'm not sure which part caused it not functioning before because i had tried it several time. but after implemented the 'action' => ['purchase/pay',$model->pcid], it's working. Tq

Comment: glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the problem regarding csrf validation, just make sure in your config about enableCsrfValidation  :

**just put this function in your controller**

```
public function beforeAction($action) {
$this->enableCsrfValidation = false;
return parent::beforeAction($action);
}
```

Let me know please.

Comment: i put the function before my action. but still not working.

Comment: as you said before you was getting #400 error, so this is the solution for that.